# Issue in creating a Route53 record using python Boto3 mapping to a static host website bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I have a developed code to create a Route 53 in AWS using python boto3 to map the record to the s3 website endpoint. But I am facing the  below error
sp19.scorecarts.com.s3-website-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
Error creating A record: An error occurred (InvalidChangeBatch) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: [Tried to create an alias that targets sp19.domainname.com.s3-website-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com., type A in zone XXXXX, but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone, Tried to create an alias that targets sp19.domainname.com.s3-website-ap-south-1.amazonaws.com., type A in zone XXXX, but that target was not found]

Here is my code

```
import boto3
import uuid

def create_route53_alias_record(domain_name, record_name, s3_website_endpoint, hosted_zone_id, region):
    try:
        AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="XXXXXX"
        AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="XXXXX"
        route53_client = boto3.client('route53',  aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                                      aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)

        print(s3_website_endpoint)
        # Create the A record with an alias to the S3 website endpoint
        changes = [{
            'Action': 'CREATE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {
                'Name': f'{record_name}.{domain_name}.',
                'Type': 'A',
                'AliasTarget': {
                    'DNSName': s3_website_endpoint,
                    'EvaluateTargetHealth': False,
                    'HostedZoneId': hosted_zone_id,  
                },
            },
        }]

        response = route53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
            HostedZoneId=hosted_zone_id,
            ChangeBatch={
                'Changes': changes
            }
        )

        print(f"A record '{record_name}.{domain_name}' created successfully.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating A record: {e}")
        return False

# Usage example
domain_name = "domainname.com"
record_name = "sp19"
AWS_REGION = "ap-south-1"
s3_bucket_name = "sp19.domainname.com"
hosted_zone_id = "Z32UXXX" 

# Generate the S3 website endpoint
s3_website_endpoint = f"{s3_bucket_name}.s3-website-{AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com"

# Create Route 53 A record with alias to the S3 website endpoint
create_route53_alias_record(domain_name, record_name, s3_website_endpoint, hosted_zone_id, AWS_REGION)
```

My bucket is static hosted and i can access the website using bucket url.Even i am able to create a record using AWS console.
But only when i am trying to create with python Boto3 i am facing this issue

Comment: Hi @psp. I updated the answer with a code example that worked for me. Please note, that you should pass both s3 hosted zone and your hosted zone IDs. And the `s3_website_endpoint` differ from region to region.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here: `but the alias target name does not lie within the target zone` - so you can't create an alias because the bucket must have the same name as your domain or subdomain. For example, if you want to use the subdomain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the name of the bucket must be [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Note: an S3 bucket that's configured as a website endpoint doesn't support SSL/TLS, so you need to route traffic to the CloudFront distribution and use the S3 bucket as the origin for the distribution.

[Documentation1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html)
[Documentation2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/s3.html#s3_website_region_endpoints)

UPDATE: you should be using `your_hosted_zone_id` for route53_client API call, and `s3_hosted_zone_in` in the changes object. Here is an example

```
import boto3
import uuid

def create_route53_alias_record(domain_name, record_name, s3_website_endpoint, s3_hosted_zone_id, your_hosted_zone_id region):
    try:
        # export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="export your values"
        # export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="export your values"
        # export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="export your values"

        route53_client = boto3.client('route53')

        print(s3_website_endpoint)
        # Create the A record with an alias to the S3 website endpoint
        changes = [{
            'Action': 'CREATE',
            'ResourceRecordSet': {

                'Name': f'{record_name}.{domain_name}',
                'Type': 'A',
                'AliasTarget': {
                    'DNSName': s3_website_endpoint,
                    'EvaluateTargetHealth': False,
                    'HostedZoneId': s3_hosted_zone_id,  
                },
            },
        }]

        response = route53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
            HostedZoneId=your_hosted_zone_id,
            ChangeBatch={
                'Changes': changes
            }
        )

        print(f"A record '{record_name}.{domain_name}' created successfully.")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error creating A record: {e}")
        return False

# Usage example
domain_name = "domainname.com"
record_name = "sp19"
AWS_REGION = "ap-south-1"
s3_bucket_name = "sp19.domainname.com"
s3_hosted_zone_id = "here should be Zone ID from Documentation2"
your_hosted_zone_id = "here should be your id"
# Generate the S3 website endpoint
s3_website_endpoint = f"s3-website.{AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com." # Here should be the endpoint from Documentation2

# Create Route 53 A record with an alias to the S3 website endpoint
create_route53_alias_record(domain_name, record_name, s3_website_endpoint, s3_hosted_zone_id, your_hosted_zone_id, AWS_REGION)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thank u for ur answer.While trying with the above changes i am getting the below error. An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ChangeResourceRecordSets operation: User: arn:aws:iam::853742496141:user/xxx is not authorized to access this resource.Even though i am able to create the Route53 record using the aws console.

Comment: 'ResourceRecordSet': {  'Name': f'{record_name}.{domain_name}','Type': 'A','AliasTarget': {                    'DNSName': s3_website_endpoint,
                    'EvaluateTargetHealth': False,
                    'HostedZoneId': s3_hosted_zone_id,  
                },
            },
        }]
       response = route53_client.change_resource_record_sets(
            HostedZoneId=your_hosted_zone_id,
            ChangeBatch={
                'Changes': changes
            }
        )
s3_hosted_zone_id = "Z11RGJOFQNVJUP"
your_hosted_zone_id = "Z2FDTNDATAQYW2"

Comment: Hi @psp, most likely, you're using default profile. Could you confirm that `Z2FDTNDATAQYW2` exists in `ap-south-1` in `853742496141`?

Comment: also, check `aws sts get-caller-identity` and `aws configure get region` in your terminal to verify all is set right.

Comment: Now it worked after changing it to correct host id. Thank you for the comments

Comment: Sure. Please, consider to vote the answer if it helped to resolve